# X.509 Are all parts of a DN optional?

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, x509certificate, x509

Are all the parts of the DN in a X.509 optional?
From RFC3280:

> Implementations of this specification MUST    be prepared to receive
>   the following standard attribute types in    issuer and subject
>   (section 4.1.2.6) names:
>
> ```
>   * country,
>   * organization,
>   * organizational-unit,
>   * distinguished name qualifier,
>   * state or province name,
>   * common name (e.g., "Susan Housley"), and
>   * serial number.
> ```

I could not find if any of these is mandatory.
I am asking because I am seeing a certificate that is signed by a trusted CA but in the issuer's field the `CN` is missing (and the `C` but I don't think that's important).
I was expecting that `CN` is mandatory. Is it?
Is there any security implications of the omission of the`CN` from the issuer's field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Bruno says, there is no requirement in RFC3280 for an Issuer DN to have a CN. 
RFC3280 states:

> The issuer field MUST contain a non-empty distinguished name (DN).

However, RFC3280 does not make any requirement on which RDN(s) should be present. Most CAs do include a CN in the Issuer DN, but some don't, such as this Equifax CA.

> OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority,O = Equifax,C = US

Or this Verisign CA.

> OU = VeriSign Trust Network,OU = "(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For
>   authorized use only",OU = Class 3 Public Primary Certification
>   Authority - G2,O = "VeriSign, Inc.",C = US

Path building and validation using RFC3280 does not require a CN in the Issuer DN.

Comment: I find this strange though. I would expect that for a very strict processing one could even impose restrictions based on the `CN` of the issuer as well

Comment: There's nothing to stop someone developing an app or creating a certificate policy that imposes restrictions on the Issuer DN for a particular PKI community. However, for general certificate use over the internet we look to RFC3280 and this has no requirement for a CN to be present in the Issuer DN.

Answer (score 1):

The RFC says that the name of the subject may be present in Subject Alternative Name extension. Section 4.2.1.7 says the following (which must be your case):

> Further, **if** the only subject identity included in the certificate is
>      an alternative name form (e.g., an electronic mail address), **then the
>      subject distinguished name MUST be empty** (an empty sequence), and the
>      subjectAltName extension MUST be present.  If the subject field
>      contains an empty sequence, the subjectAltName extension MUST be
>      marked critical.

Comment: There is no Subject Alternative Name extension present in the certificate and there is no extension marked as critical.The only DN present is in the `Issuer` field that has `OU` (3 different `OU` value pairs) and an `O`.Firefox gives a warning that `Owner: This website does not supply ownership information`. So does this warning mean that indeed there is a problem with the `CN` here? What are the security implications?

Comment: @user384706 As the certificate doesn't prove ownership and authenticity, it can't be used for properly authenticating the web server. Security implications are that if such certificate is stolen, it can be installed to any web site. Consequently, such certificates must not be trusted. For a web site the certificate must include web host name or IP address in the certificate. This is defined by RFC 2818 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt) in 3.1.

Comment: May be I lost you here. The certificate does include the domain name of the web site in the `Subject` field of the certificate. The `Subject` field has a `CN` and it is the domain name of the site (the same as I see in the URL bar). It is the `Issuer` field that does not have a `CN` (and I assume that is the meaning of the warning in firefox). Does this change your last comment? Or am I missundestanding your answer?

Comment: @user384706, don't stress too much about `Owner: This website does not supply ownership information`, it's populated with C, O and a few others (but not OU, I think) with EV certs. The Firefox UI can be quite confusing in that respect. Even `https://www.google.com/` has that. Unlike the subject, [the issuer field MUST contain a non-empty distinguished name (DN).](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.4), but that doesn't mean it needs a CN RDN.

Comment: @Bruno:Ok. So for validation purpose the `CN` of the `Issuer` does not convey any important information?

Comment: @user384706: not really, it's just a naming convention. At the end of the day, either you trust that CA or you don't. However it's called is an administrative matter. It's certainly better if it has a name that makes sense to you, but whether it's using a CN isn't vital.

Comment: @user384706 I have misread your question (though it's about Subject, not issuer) and I'd delete the answer if there were no such extensive communication in comments. Feel free to downvote :).

Answer (score 0):

X509 certificates should compare the whole dn.  That is

```
Dn1 == Dn2
```

> Two distinguished names DN1 and DN2 match if they
> have the same number of RDNs, for each RDN in DN1 there is a matching
> RDN in DN2, and the matching RDNs appear in the same order in both
> DNs.

Each component is optional, they may be repeated.  However a match requires all the fields match.

From [ietf rfc5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)